# TimerTask stop all other execution

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have a program that starts a timer and then repeats code every second, before it stops.  What happens is it does not stop the execution coming from main.  I am assuming it is only one thread that is running along with it, but from looking at posts I am still not sure how to temporarily halt that.

```
final class DogDoor{
  private static DogDoor dogDoor;
  private boolean open;

  private DogDoor(){
    open=false;
  }

  public static synchronized DogDoor getDogDoor(){
    if(dogDoor==null){
      dogDoor=new DogDoor();
    }
    return dogDoor;
  }

  public void activate(){
    open=!open;
    System.out.println(open? "Door is open!": "Door is closed!");
    if(open){
      autoClose();
    }
  }
  public void autoClose(){
    System.out.print("Door closing in 5 seconds . . .");

    //right before it starts the timer and task
    timer();

    //then resume here after the timer completes
    activate();
  }
  public void timer(){
    new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(
      new java.util.TimerTask(){

        //Prefer to stop until this completes
        int s=5;
        @Override
        public void run(){
          System.out.print(" .");
          if((s--)==0){
            cancel();
          }
        }
      }, 0, 1000);
  }
}

final class Remote{
  private static Remote remote;
  private boolean windowsLocked;
  private int lockCode;

  public Remote(){
    windowsLocked=true;
    generateLockCode();
  }

  public static synchronized Remote getRemote(){
    if(remote==null){
      remote=new Remote();
    }
    return remote;
  }
  public String getLockCode(){
    return String.format("%03d", lockCode);
  }

  public boolean windowsLocked(){
    return windowsLocked;
  }
  public void generateLockCode(){
    lockCode=(int)(Math.random()*1000);
  }
  public void toggleDoor(){
    DogDoor.getDogDoor().activate();
  }
  public void fixWindows(){
    if(passCodeVerifier()){
      windowsLocked=!windowsLocked;
      System.out.println(windowsLocked? "Windows locked!": "Windows unlocked!");
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Invalid passcode!");
    }
  }
  public boolean passCodeVerifier(){
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter three digit keypad code: ");
    return scanner.hasNext("^\\d{3}$") && Integer.parseInt(scanner.next())==(lockCode);
  }
}

public class DogDoorDemo{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Dog door demo.");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(Remote.getRemote().getLockCode());
    Remote.getRemote().toggleDoor();

    //and finally resume here
    Remote.getRemote().fixWindows();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what your question is. What would you like to halt and when?

Comment: A Timer is not supposed to stop execution of the calling code -- that's one of the main reasons for using it.

Comment: Perhaps why I didn't find an answer... whats an alternative?  @Rodit I am trying to stop everything else, until the 5 second duration on the door timer, and complete autoclose, the main function execution which asks for the password

Comment: I would not use a Timer but another construct, say a CountDownLatch, and this way would be notified when the latch is done.

Comment: Or use a Timer with a CountDownLatch, but the latch's `await()` method will pause the calling thread until the it has completed its count down.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you.. I tried this and learned the CountDownLatch class

Comment: You're welcome. Or even more simply, don't use a Timer but rather a ScheduledExecutorService, call `shutdown()` on the service after adding all tasks, and then call `awaitTermination(...)` on the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the documentation, Timers are:

```
A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a **background thread**
```

This means any part of the program run using a TimerTask will be run on a separate thread from the main one, and therefore will not block execution on the main thread.

An alternative solution would be to sleep the thread for the desired amount of seconds as follows (replace your timer() method with this one and catch the InterruptedException.):

```
void timer(int seconds)throws InterruptedException{
    for(int i = 0; i < seconds; i++){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Output whatever message you want to appear every second. The variable 'i' will hold the current second in the countdown.
    }
}
```

And replace your autoClose method with this:

```
public void autoClose(){
    System.out.print("Door closing in 5 seconds . . .");

    //right before it starts the timer and task
    timer(5);

    //then resume here after the timer completes
    activate();
}
```

`Thread#sleep` throws an `InterruptedException` so this must be handled appropriately.

Comment: Looks like putting this in main after remote.toggleDoor which initiate the timer, still does not prevent the output "Door is closed."

Comment: Sorry, I think you have misunderstood where to put this. I'll make it more clear in a second @DannyP.

Comment: Okay I understand, it will replace timer that I wrote